# Best way to read/write data to Google Sheets

Tags: java, android, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create an Android app (Java) to read and write data to a GoogleSheet.

I followed this guide:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java

but I got following error stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/cn.leo.zxingview/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes7.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~3LMO7u4xh20M6CUbBAGxyw==/cn.leo.zxingview-TgsY52whz0D3_gD6p0ZalA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~3LMO7u4xh20M6CUbBAGxyw==/cn.leo.zxingview-TgsY52whz0D3_gD6p0ZalA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:127)
```

Here is the content of build.gradle dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.32.1'
    implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.26.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev20210629-1.32.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20211107-1.32.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.33.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

I know this guide has been made for java, I'm surprised google doc doesn't point to an android guide...

Does anyone have an hint for me ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use google service throuh Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

One needs to create Google Cloud Platform (free) client ID for android. read this page: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-api-key

```
class GoogleHandler {
private Sheets service;
private Exception mLastError = null;

public GoogleHandler(GoogleAccountCredential credential){
    NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    this.service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,jsonFactory,credential)
            .setApplicationName("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .build();
}

public void readCurrentWarehouse(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            String spreadsheetId = "";
            try{
                Spreadsheet spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).execute();
                Sheet lastSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets().get(spreadsheet.getSheets().size()-1);
                String range = lastSheet.getProperties().getTitle();
                List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
                ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId,range).execute();
                List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
                if (values!=null){
                    for (List row : values){
                        results.add(row.get(0).toString());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(results.size());

            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run `gradlew -q app:dependencies`.
It should help to identify missing dependencies

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't find any "HttpServer" neither "com.sun.net" inside the file. see https://file.io/Av0UwugX2DwI